# How to fix a depth-first Sudoku solve?

Tags: python, depth-first-search, sudoku

I'm trying to create a sudoku puzzle solver in Python that uses a [depth-first](http://norvig.com/sudoku.html) "brute-force" to solve the puzzle. However, I am coming up with the same error over and over again, after having recoded many times.

I'll try my best to explain the problem as clearly as possible - as this is my first problem related to depth-first searching, it may be that I'm missing something obvious.

Here is the cut-down code (mixed with pseudo-code in places where specifics aren't necessary):

```
def solvePuzzle(puzzle):
    <while the puzzle is still not solved>:
        <make a copy of the puzzle>
        <go through each unsolved box>: 
            <try to find the value of the box>
            <if the current solution is impossible, return to the parent branch>
        <if the copy of the puzzle is exactly the same as the puzzle now, no changes have been made, so its time to start branching into different possibilities>:      
            <pick a random box to guess the number of>
            <go through each possible value and run solvePuzzle() on that puzzle>:
                <if a solution is returned, return it>
                <else, try the next possible value>
    <return the puzzle>
```

That's as cut down as I could make it - sorry if its still a bit of a read/confusing.

For some reason, even after setting the program to solvePuzzle() each created copy of the puzzle, it finds that all of the copies are impossible (by impossible, I mean an error has been made in a guess). This can't be possible, as every number is being tested!

[Here's the full code](http://pastie.org/8172523) (only about 50 lines of code), in case that's not clear enough.

If anyone could even *suggest* why this wouldn't be working, I'd be greatly thankful.

Thank you!

**Edit:** [As promised, here's the "isSolved()" method.](http://pastie.org/8172563)

Comment: Instead of looping over `i` in `xrange(81)`, why not loop over `i` and `j` each in `xrange(9)`? (and rename your current `j` to `k`, of course.)

Comment: I guess it is a bit more confusing to read, but it still does work. If it helps to answer my problem, I could write a quick version that uses your suggestion for you?

Comment: Your problem is probably in `isSolved()`, just from what you're saying.

Comment: It's not just more confusing to read - it's more error-prone to write. You could've easily mixed up `i / 9` and `i % 9` somewhere.

Comment: @user2357112 I double-checked that profusely; I wasn't joking when I said I re-coded this a few times, and I made sure that's not the case

Comment: @2rs2ts isSolved() is even simpler: I'll link it in the question

Comment: Ok, I'm baffled by your `isSolved()`. I had this exact assignment in freshman year of undergrad and the way I did it was to write a function which checks for contradictions (2 of the same number in any row, column, or house). My data structure was a 2-d list with `None` as my placeholder value. My backtracking algorithm found the first cell with `None` in it and `for x in xrange(1,10)` it inserted that number into the cell and recursed - if that came back `False`, it would try the next `x`, until all failed or it was solved. The backtracker returned `isSolved() if not isSolved() else puzzle`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the "Sets the value if its the only one that can be made in the box" part is wrong. It doesn't check whether the value is permitted in that square before assigning it.

Comment: Of course, I realize that I'm trying to trumpet what my freshman self did, which is quite silly. But, I hope that saying that might give you an idea of an approach which you could take which is IMHO a lot lot simpler.

Comment: @user2357112 It does check if its permitted, by starting with all permitted values and eliminating from that.

Comment: I believe the `puzzle` structure maintains a list of legal values for each cell, or an integer for known values.  So it's solved if no remaining cell has more than one possible value.  Similarly, the 'if its the only one that can be made in the box' checks all legal values for the cell to see if there's anywhere else in the box they can go.  It assigns them if it finds a single value with no other legal location - "this box must have a 7 and no other cell can take one, so it must go here."  You could apply the same logic to columns and rows, though of course brute force will do it in the end.

Comment: hmm... yeah, never mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suspect that the problem is here:

```
# Go through each possibility in the branch until one solution is found
clone = deepcopy(puzzle)
values = clone[index / 9][index % 9]
for value in values:
    clone[index / 9][index % 9] = value
    branch = solvePuzzle(clone)
    # If a list is returned, it worked! Otherwise, try the next possibility
    if isinstance(branch, list):
        return branch
```

That mutates the `clone` copy for each candidate value, and does not restore to the semi-solved puzzle state when it finds a contradiction.  Try this:

```
# Go through each possibility in the branch until one solution is found
values = puzzle[index / 9][index % 9]
for value in values:
    clone = deepcopy(puzzle)
    clone[index / 9][index % 9] = value
    branch = solvePuzzle(clone)
    # If a list is returned, it worked! Otherwise, try the next possibility
    if isinstance(branch, list):
        return branch
```

Comment: I would be surprised if there is only one problem. The code is too complex and redundant.

Comment: It worked! I see now why that could be a problem: I guess that clone was passed by reference instead of value. Thank you very much!

Comment: @user2357112 Can you explain that please? I understand why it may be complex with the xrange(81), but why is it redundant?

Comment: Yeah, all Python variables are by reference.

Comment: @Sim: The "Sets the value if its the only one that can be made in the box" part is unnecessary. It also doesn't check the row or column, and I believe it's bugged. The constant recomputation of the indices of the current cell is also redundant.

Comment: @user2357112 It does check for rows and columns. This is commented under "Checks rows" and "Checks columns".

Comment: @Sim: No, I mean it doesn't do an equivalent of the "Sets the value if its the only one that can be made in the box" thing for the row or column.